# How do you put together a cross-compiler for yourself?

Tags: clang, llvm, cross-compiling

I'm sort of surprised that I can't find much info on how to put together a cross-architecture or cross-os compiler using llvm, from scratch.  llvm itself works out of the box.  Then you just need to gather the sysroot from the target system, and then somehow generate and integrate cross-platform binutils?

While I have a huge number of random use cases, my immediate annoyance is with CodeSourcery being ... basically gone for targeting arm/linux, building on Windows.

Comment: I think this is a good question (though you don't really state one in the body). It probably would have been welcomed on the old Stack Overflow. It will probably be closed as too broad on the current version of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yeah, kinda sorta.  But I would say there isn't much open to opinion, which is probably the primary annoyance with bad stack overflow questions.  I really want to know about LLVM/clang specifically.  I noticed you edited my subject to take that out.

Comment: As for the edit, see [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190). Titles like *Tag:* and *Tag -* have to be cleaned up.

Comment: Heh, cool, thanks for pointing that out, I'm not going to debate the community (but disagree since it forces humans to act like computers and integrate different information without reading English).   Interesting that you suggest that I don't repeat the tag, but should repeat the question....  (sorry, couldn't resist).

Comment: Actually I guess my question should be "How do you put together something." and then you could look at the tags and figure it out!

Comment: For what its worth, I disagree too. I'm one of the dissenting opinions on that (or similar) Meta questions. I just try and follow site policies :)

Comment: Heh, well, in any case thank you for helping me form a more conforming question.

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on a cross compilation tool chain based on clang/LLVM. It currently runs on various Linux platforms (ARM, Mips, PowerPC, x86) and Windows x86. I try to stay up to date with the current LLVM source tree and bring in the latest versions of binutils, GDB, etc. as they get released.(see http://ellcc.org/blog/?page_id=467).
I had a few major design goals for the project, but two were top priority. I wanted the entire tool chain to be able to build itself, which it does for all the Linux targets, and in the spirit of clang, I wanted as few support binaries as possible. To that end, I build binutils with options for most of the executables to support all of the targets. Each processor gets its own **as** (which LLVM is eliminating the need for as more internal assembler support becomes available), but I build just one **ld**, **objdump**, **gdb**, etc, that can handle all the different targets.

From a clean source install, I first build clang/LLVM and binutils/GDB with gcc, then I build all the libraries (C/C++, compiler-rt, etc.) for all the targets. A second, optional build uses the newly built tools to compile themselves. After that, subsequent builds are self hosting.

I build all the tools for the various hosts on my x86 Linux box, but each tool chain should in theory be able to recreate themselves on the other Linux hosts or on Windows.

If you're interested in pre-built binaries, they are available at  http://ellcc.org/blog/?page_id=20295

Comment: Wow.  I guess that given your project you saw no other way forward than to build libraries from scratch?  I just assumed there was some tool for gathering a sysroot from the target (either huge/complete or some subset based on a specification).

Comment: I just gathered the libraries that I needed to build clang/LLVM, binutils, and gdb. I wanted to build from source rather than pull in pre-compiled libraries for all the target processors.